# authorProfileImageUrl returns only a tiny thumbnail

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to use YouTube Data API to get a list of comments for a video.
The problem is that the field `authorProfileImageUrl` in the response contains a URL to a tiny thumbnail (28x28 pixels) of the profile image instead of the bigger one (48x48) that can be seen in YouTube's comment section. How can I retrieve the bigger one? Am I missing some magic parameter in the request that selects the size of the profile images in comments?

Here's my request URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?videoId=VIDEO_ID&part=snippet&fields=pageInfo,items(snippet(topLevelComment(id,snippet(authorDisplayName,authorChannelUrl,authorProfileImageUrl,authorChannelId,textDisplay,likeCount,publishedAt)),totalReplyCount))&maxResults=3&key=API_KEY
```

**Edit:**
Here's an example profile pic URL i get:

```
https://yt3.ggpht.com/-b-fXZSZ0hPw/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/mq4JpF46xq4/s28-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg
                                                                        ^^
```

I noticed that the marked part seems to select the size, because when I change the `28` to `48`, the size of the profile pic changes too.

I could change it "manually" with some fancy regexp, and it will work, but it will also rely on implementation details that are undocumented and that may change in future and render the application broken :P  So it really would be better if there was a documented API way to do that.

Comment: The api doesnt return it but you might be able to take the id returned and pass it though the Google+ api this wont work all the time not evey one has their google+ account linked to their youtube account anymore.

Comment: So how does YouTube do it so that they have nice 48x48 profile images for *every* comment when *they* display the comment section?

Comment: They probly have the files they just haven't exposed it to us.   There is a lot that isnt exposed though the apis.

Comment: So what's the point of making an API and even calling it 'Data' if it doesn't expose all the data? :q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like nobody knows how to solve this, ho here's my temporary solution.
It works, but it depends on an implementation detail that can change in the future and then the solution will break apart and will have to be corrected :q

I accept my own answer for now, but when someone posts a better one, I'll accept it instead.

The solution:
I made a simple function that searches for the image size in the URL string and replaces it with a bigger size.

```
function small2big(url)
{
   return url.replace(/(\/.*s)28(.*\/photo.jpg)$/,"$1"+"48"+"$2");
}
```

Oh, and here's my middle finger for you, Google: `,,|,,`

Comment: I appreciate this, and I was trying to convert this over to php when I accidentally discovered that if you remove everything right at the '/s28', the entire photo displays in it's normal size. For example, https://yt3.ggpht.com/-b-fXZSZ0hPw/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/mq4JpF46xq4/

Answer (score 1):

It seems that actually removing everything right at the 's28' will display the entire image without specifying a size.

For example, instead of this:
https://yt3.ggpht.com/-b-fXZSZ0hPw/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/mq4JpF46xq4/s28-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg

You can use this: https://yt3.ggpht.com/-b-fXZSZ0hPw/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/mq4JpF46xq4/

And it will return the full size image.

In my case, using php I simply:

```
function bigAvatar($url) {
   $url = substr($url, 0, strpos($url, 's28'));
   return $url;
}
```

Again, if google decides to change this in the future, this would break. But for now, it works.